# Create a new variable every time I import a list file

Tags: list-manipulation, import

I want to import a list and put it in a variable. The number of lists grows as the days go by, so I do not know their final number.

to import the first file I use this code:

```
data1 = Import["C:\\Users\\filename.csv", {"Data"}]
```

the second:

```
data2 = Import["C:\\Users\\filename.csv", {"Data"}]
```

Is there a way to do this automatically for any file I choose? Or put it in a certain folder?

Comment: You can use `Symbol` to create dynamically named variables. However, whatever you do can and should be made with lists instead of named variables.

Comment: How is `data2` recognizable from `data1`? i.e., if you were to look at the two data files, how would you tell them apart?

Comment: Each list is a data of object placement on a surface by time. data1 it object 1 and data 2 it object 2. The information within the list is almost identical, so just by looking at the contents of the list I will not be able to discern to whom it belongs.

Comment: I think you should write AppendTo[data,Import[]]. Then you easily can iterate the data. But something is missing in your question. Do you expect the data to be saved in the notebook? If not you should automatically read all the import files.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to solve this.

If you insist on using names, you can create a new name by e.g.:

```
count=0;
Symbol["data",ToString[++count]]= Import[...]
Symbol["data",ToString[++count]]= Import[...] ...
```

However, it will be a pain working with all these different data sets. It will be much easier, as already mentioned, to pack them in a list and index them. E.g.:

```
data={};
AppendTo[data,Import[...]]
AppendTo[data,Import[...]] ...
```

You may even automate the import. E.g. if you have a file in some directory and you want to check every hour if a new file arrived. If yes, read the file and then delete it:

```
data = {};
obj = SessionSubmit[ScheduledTask[
   If[FileExistsQ[ filename], AppendTo[data, Import[filename]]; 
    DeleteFile[filename];], "Hourly"]]
```

Comment: Instead of incrementing a variable like count one can use Unique[].

Comment: And how do you remember the name?

Comment: If symbol names starting with "data" are only used for this, one can use Evaluate[Unique["data"]]=Import[] and get the symbol names with Names["data*"] and get for instance the value of the newest import with Symbol[Names["data*"][[-1]]].